# How to use pd.cut with LARGE number of Bins?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

***TLDR:*** How can I assign records in a `pandas.Series` to a `pd.category` when there are >3M bins/categories? Currently trying `pd.cut` but that is intractable.

I have some data that I run through a histogram and then finding the peaks of the histogram using `peakutils`. Then I am splitting the data more or less between peaks. I have a quick process to do this and the results look more or less like the following.

Say I have a peak at bin locations `[5, 9, 16]`. I want to assign all the data that lie in bins `[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]` to class `0`. The data in `[8, 9, 10, 11, 12]` to class `1` and the data in `[13, 14, 15, 16, ...]` to class `2`.

The total number of bins return is a lot (> 3M). This is ok, as my peak finding stuff is quick. The **probelm** is that when I try to map my bins back to my original data using `pd.cut` things become intractable.

In normal cases my code something like the following

```
# data is a pd.Series with about 600k records in it
hist, edges = np.histogram(data, bins='fd')
peakIndex = peakutils.indexes(hist, thres=0.01, min_dist=10)
peaks_counts = np.zeros(len(enges)-1)

# takes forever when length of `edges` >= 3M
bdata = pd.cut(data, bins=edges, include_lowest=True) # <-- This is what needs to be sped up
bdata["codes"] = bdata[data.name].cat.codes
midpoints = peakIndex[:-1\ + np.ceil(np.diff(peakIndex)/2)
midpoints = np.insert(midpoints, 0, 0)
midpoints = np.append(midpoints, len(edges))

# merge the non point bins with the bins that are peaks as described above. 
for ix in range(len(midpoints)):
    _from = midpoints[ix].astype(int)
    _to = midpoints[ix].astype(int)
    current_peak = np.arange(_from, _to)
    bdata["codes"] = bdata["codes"].replace(current_peak, [edges[ix] for e in current_peak])
```

The counts of the histogram `hist` has A LOT of `0` counts. So I thought I could be clever and remove the bins that had a count of `0`. Doing this reduced my total number of bins for `pd.cut` to loop over to be in the `37k` range. It was able to do this in an acceptable amount of time. The problem came I think with the `cat.codes` for the bins. They no long lined up with my `current_peak`.

As I am writing this I just thought of something but gotta try it and I'll still ask this in-case someone smarter than myself has better idea. Maybe I can index the `bdata` edges with the values of `edges` or something like this.

Any way I hope this was clear..

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of digging around Pandas source code I found that the slow part of `pd.cut` is not the mapping of data to bins, but rather the creation of the categorical data type. More or less what I did is as follows:

```
bins = pd.core.algorithms.unique(bins) # probably not really needed but hey why take the chance

# this is what maps data to bins and its pretty quick
ids = pd.core.dtypes.common.ensure_int64(bins.searchsorted(data, side="left"))
ids[data == bins[0]] = 1 # this is the include lowest feature of `pd.cut`

labels = pd.core.reshape.tile._format_labels(bins, 3, right=True, include_lowest=True)
labels = pd.Categorical(labels, categories=labels, ordered=True)

bdata = pd.core.algorithms.take_nd(labels, ids - 1)
bdata = pd.DataFrame(bdata)
bdata["codes"] = ids
```

Hope this helps someone else with a similar problem. If you have any questions I'll do my best to answer them.